# How to write methods in functional components ? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the Hooks part of the React documentation at it seems like now there is not a huge difference between the class and functional components. I was trying to implement the React's example from their homepage using functional components but I don't know how to write the methods since functions don't have methods.

If I make inline functions like:

```
const handleClick = () => {}
```

Won't it be unoptimized ? Since it's created every time the element is rendered. Or am I wrong ?

If I make external functions, how will I update the states ?

In general isn't it more tedious to use functional components ?

Also in general, is it possible to do anything using functional components after the introduction of hooks ? Is it a good idea ?

Following is the code, it's also available on React's homepage.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="new-todo">
            What needs to be done?
          </label>
          <input
            id="new-todo"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
          <button>
            Add #{this.state.items.length + 1}
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: Date.now()
    };
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ''
    }));
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried making external functions but that doesn't seem very neat. I'm thinking there might be some developed best practices that will be better than mine.

Comment: The optimization is done with `useCallback` for inline functions and `useMemo` for computationally expensive values/variables.

Comment: Using external functions can also be valid, they just might need a lot of arguments in their scope, that can get ugly. If your React component is really heavy with lifecycle stuff, DOM refs etc., it can still be valid to use a class component imho. The typical form handling stuff is fine as a function component.

Comment: React Community itself is promoting usage of functional based components, ultimately when you write anything with class based components they are converted into functions (so you save a lot of time here).With introduction of hooks you can achieve everything which you can do with class based components , you have less code to write since class based has ton's of lifecycles methods.

Comment: yes, with useCallback you can optimize this functions, but i believe rebuilding the fn in every render is not a bad performance, also if you use some kind of state m management, you could get this performance for free.

Comment: "*Won't it be unoptimized?*" - does it actually matter, have you measured the difference? Sounds like [premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) to me. Creating functions is fast in modern engines. There's a lot more cruft that React creates on every render that could be optimised away.

Comment: "*If I make external functions, how will I update the states?*" - just pass the state setter as an argument.

Comment: @aleEspinosaM and timotgl: No, `useCallback` does *not* prevent the recreation of the function on every render.

Comment: Btw, these are called **function** components, there's nothing function**al** about them

Comment: useCallback does not optimize the code at all. It only keeps some references, so you can use them in dependencies

Answer (score 0):

So, it is not a big deal to use functions inside react components.
If you can store it outside (for example into `utils.js` file which is located beside you component) it will lighten your component.

But sometimes we depend on data which stores inside our components. If you pass function to child components you can wrap it with `useCallback` hook:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback to avoid unnecessary re-render of child components.

In general functional components are much easier to read and test because they are plain JavaScript functions without state and internal lifecycle, you end up with less code.

Comment: "*you can optimize it with useCallback hook*" - what exactly is optimised there? I don't think it does what you (or the OP) might expect.

Comment: With the useCallback hook, we can memoize a function and get an instance from it which will only change if one of the dependencies changes. This means React will use the same function's reference between renders instead of re-creating it.

Comment: That is not true. useCallback saves the reference of the first function after dependency change. It is still created on each render and garbage collected.

Comment: "In this case you can optimize it with useCallback hook". You can not optimize this with useCallback. as it says, it memoizes the reference, but it does not prevent from creating a new one on each render.

Comment: “useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.” - React docs. This way we use a function that is not changed on every render.  Can't this be called an optimization?

Comment: No. As it says, it will keep the reference of the function. But it simply can not prevent creating a new function on each render. Example: useCallback(() => ({}), []) is exactly same as const cb = () => ({}); useCallback(cb, []). In this example cb will be recreated on each render. The returned value from useCallback will be the reference of the first created "cb", but it has nothing to stop from creating a new function on next render. "cb" will have new reference. It makes the performance worse, because now it has to track dependencies on each render as well

Comment: All right, I get it  So, if I say: “useCallback always degrades performance” - is it a valid statement?

Comment: If used alone - yes. If used with combination with useMemo, memo, the diffing algorithm - no. This is why it exists